# Sitecore - How to load images on CD server from CM server?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have two separated servers: one is CD server and one is CM Server. I upload images on CM server and publish them. On the web database, although I saw the the images under Media Library item

[image]

But they aren't displayed on CD server (e.g on website), it indicates that the images not found. Please help me to know how I can solve that problem or I do need some configuration for that.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are the images/items visible in the web-database on CM? How did you try to load the image on the CD, are you rendering the image or just retrieving it using the Media Handler?

Comment: @Rob, yes, images are visible in web db on CM. On CD, I just call the code to render the image:  Html.Sitecore().Field("Image", item, new { alt = item.ImageAlt("Image") })

Comment: can you try to retrieve the image by it's URL? This may as well be a Context or Rendering issue.

Comment: @Rob, It just return the url "/-/media/imagename"

Comment: Are Media Library images stored in database or on the file system? What is the type of "item" you use in your code? Is it Sitecore Item with extension method "ImageAlt"?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, Images are stored on the file system. Item is just an object has a filed called image. ImageAlt is an extension

Comment: If you want to stored media item as files, you need to store them on a shared drive, not on CM server only.

Comment: @MarekMusielak, I'm using Sitecore clound on Azure

Comment: @Jonathan You shouldn't use storage on file system when using a multi-instance environment. Take a look at the scaling guide for that and other recommended configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore media items can carry actual media file either as:

- Blob in the database - everything works automatically OOB
- Files on the file system - one needs to configure either [WebDeploy, or DFS](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_usletter.pdf)

Database resources are costly, you might not want to waste them on something that can be achieved by free tools.

Since WebDeploy by default locates modified files by comparing file hashes between source, and target, it will become slower after a while.

Answer (score 0):

You might have uploaded image in media library as a file. As such, image is stored as a File on file system. To verify this, your image item in media library will have a path value set in 'File Path' field of your image item. Such files have to be moved to file system of CD server as well. 
If you uploaded your images in bulk, you can store them as blob in DB by default rather than as a File in file system using following setting-

```
<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="false">
```